# NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDIalectProvider

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I created a simple cucumber test that returns a sequence number.
The project builds successfully.
I am using the Intellij IDE.
When I try to run the cucumber test, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18) ....

This is a gradle build and I have these dependencies listed below:

```
testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:3.0.2')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:3.0.2')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:3.0.2')
    testCompile('io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:3.0.2')
```

In other posts, it states to remove transitive dependencies, such as the cucumber-java, junit and jvm but I still get the error.
I also tried adding gherkin: `io.cucumber:gherkin:3.2.0 but it gives the same error.

I found a table referring to the version of gherkin that goes with cucumber and for cucumber 3x there is no gherkin version to add.

So I am at a loss as to way I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you running it via the CLI or within some IDE? Try `./gradlew clean test` in the CLI first.

Comment: Sorry...I am using Intellij IDE

Comment: Does the test run without errors in the command line using `./gradlew clean test`?

Comment: That command did not work. I used `gradle clean test` and it ran successfully.

Comment: OK, then your IDE is the problem. And by the way, it's recommended to use the Gradle Wrapper and not `gradle` — but that's a story for another day. To make this work you might need to delete the **output** directory created by IntelliJ IDEA (not to confuse with `.idea/`, and probably also do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: When I try to run the test in the IDE by right-clicking on the feature file, it is showing the scenarios as undefined.

Comment: @GloriaSantin Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached. Make sure to specify your IntelliJ IDEA version. Double check the issue is reproducible with 2019.2.2 release.

Comment: ok...thanks..and just for my info why is it better to use the wrapper?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html). In a nutshell, you are going to get certain guarantees, being the most common one: the project must use version `X`, but you have version `Y` and there is something dark that works in one version but not in the other.

Comment: Deleted the output directory..now it will not recreate it when I build.  The build it successful but the output directory is not in the project structure