# Unable to run a simple cucumber feature file in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I've just installed the community edition of IntelliJ and the Cucumber integration. When I try to run a feature, I get the error below. How do I fix this? I have cucumber-core 4.7.2 and gherkin 7.0.4.

```
Feature: OrangeHRM Login
  Scenario: Logo presence on OrangeHRM home page
    Given I launch chrome browser
    When I open orangeHRM homepage
    Then I verify that the logo present on page
    And close the browser
```

```
Error :
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:29)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:28)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.IGherkinDialectProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber#compatibility-matrix-for-cucumber-agents. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826925/noclassdeffounderror-gherkin-igherkindialectprovider.

Comment: You've got the wrong version of Gherkin. You should let your build tool (maven, gradle, ivy) manage your transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @mpkorstanje, you are using the wrong version of Gherkin with this version of Cucumber.

You don't need to add a Gherkin dependency yourself; this can be managed by your build tool (Maven/Gradle).

As stated in the [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/), you only need the `cucumber-java` or `cucumber-java8` dependency. Which one you need, depends on whether you want to write annotated methods or lambdas, respectively:

If you are going to use the lambda expressions API (Java 8) to write the step definitions, add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, to write them using annotated methods, add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```